# Theory on rewriting expressions to optimize them

Tags: parsing, programming-languages, expression-trees

Suppose I have a language where I can enter expression like this oversimplified example:

```
if A() > B() then A() else B() end
```

So A() and B() are functions and the expression returns the bigger of the two. The naive way of evaluating this would call both A and B, and then call the biggest of the two again. So if A returns 10 and B returns 20, B is bigger and would be called twice.

What I would like to implement is a mechanism that would undertsand that since A() and B() are deterministic (always give the same result) the expression can be rewritten to this:

```
tmpA = A()
tmpB = B()
if tmpA > tmpB then tmpA else tmpB end
```

This code would only call A and B once, if both are equally expensive this would save 33% of execution time.

I want to do this so the user does not have to worry about performance, my langiage is targeted towards business users rather than programmers. The user would enter the expressions just as (s)he would on a whiteboard, the program parses it into an expression tree and an optimizer would automagically rewrite that for efficient execution and then compile.

Does anyone know of a good book or resource that handles this topic? Is there any formal theory on this? The case above is easy to spot, but when things get more complicated I get nervous. When I rewrite an expression and change the behaviour that would not be a good thing.

A more involved example would be

```
A = 10
B = if A > 5 then 100 else 0 end
C = if A > 5 then B * 2 else 0 end
```

I won't bore you with all the details, but suppose A is a flag that indicates if something should be done. The intermedtiate function B is also a result that the user could call.

If I call C, it would check for A > 5 and then call B, wich would check A again and then return. so when I substitute (inline) the expressions, I would get

```
C = if A > 5 then if A > 5 then 100 else 0 end * 2 else 0 end
```

which can be optimized to

```
C = if A > 5 then 200 else 0
```

In a typical model there are hundreds of these expression all calling eachother of recursive, so these things can get pretty complicated. If possible I'd like to not find this out through trial and eror but tap into what others have doen in this field.

Thanks in advance,

Gert-Jan

Comment: Are you trying to determine *when* a function is deterministic?  If so, that falls into the realm of the *halting problem*, which is NP-hard.

Comment: @cdhowie Halting problem is not NP-hard, it actually is undecidable.

Comment: @Howard: Hmm, you are right.  I was researching these concepts together some time ago, and I guess they've become somewhat blurred together in my mind.  At any rate, if the language is turing-complete, the compiler cannot hope to figure out which functions are deterministic with 100% accuracy.

Comment: Hi no, the language is a lot like excel, so a reference to another 'cell' would be deterministic, and any functions i supply would have metadata to indicate if they are deterministic or not.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought but if you get your code to replace all duplicated method calls with reference to a pre-populated variable (populated on the line prior to its first call to avoid un-unnecessary calling) can you not let the compiler pick up the rest..

I could be wrong but I would have thought they would have put quite a bit of effort into those types of optimizations already.. depends on the language, compiler (and sometimes compile options) but those are faster to research than code optimization as a whole..

just a suggestion though

Comment: Hi thanks, that's pretty much what i do but the are other cases, for instance a collection of classes like a db where want to say sum(a) * sum(b) like in sql, and then the rewrite would be sum(a * b) where i would only iterate over the collection once. The idea is the user can be very naive in how he specifies what should be done and the code would still be fast.

Comment: That example should be sum(a) + sum(b) -> sum(a+b), the example above would return another result..

Comment: yeah that is tough.. implementing caching is about as far as I could take that one ;-) (I would look to compiler books if you have to get better optimization as it seems like in some way you want to create your own language and potentially a run time to to get major improvements).

Comment: the only other thing i could think of (trying to imagine why you might have ended up needing this) analysing the code to create some kind of data cube for all the commands to run against..